# how can i get the error free output of python in vs code?

Tags: python-3.x

I had install the python in my mac m1 and trying to run the python code but not getting the output and it is giving the error zsh: command not found: python. pleaser help me to get the output and make me able to work on p=vs code

i tryied to run python code in my mac1 vs code application but it is giving errors that python is not found